# Is it possible to escape a reserved word in Python?

Tags: python, syntax

It may not be a good idea to name a variable after a reserved word, but I am curious:

Is there any escape syntax in Python to allow you to use a reserved word as the name of a variable?

For example, in C# this can be done by prefixing the reserved word with `@`

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It is not possible, however it is some kind of a tradition in Python to append a `_` to get a new identifier:

```
def drive(from_, to):
    pass
```

Comment: This says we can . para3 3rd last line https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings

Comment: I can't find anything there on escaping reserved words, only a bit about how you shouldn't use `len` as a variable name (and `len` is not a keyword).

Comment: python allowed my to create a list named "list" , it should not , no idea why python allowed me to user reserved words.

Comment: @etl_devs `list` is not a reserved word, it is simply the name of a builtin. Shadowing those is generally a bad idea, but it's perfectly legal.

Answer (score 7):

**No**, this is not possible.

[Section 2.3.1 of The Python Language Reference](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#keywords) says that keywords '*cannot be used as ordinary identifiers*' and does not specify an escape syntax.

This is probably a Good Thing, for the sake of code readability!

Comment: although if you add any character to a keyword on either side as long as the result is a valid identifer, it's now distinct from the keyword. i.e. `in` is a keyword but `in2` and `xin` are not.

Comment: This says we can but shouldn't. para3 3rd last line https://developers.google.com/edu/python/strings

Comment: How on earth do you add an XML attribute with the identified "class" then?

Comment: @aWebDeveloper: if you mean the reference to "len", that is not a keyword, but a pre-defined function, so it can be redefined at will.

Comment: @Stephen For "class": https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26764634/etree-subelement-attribute-name-class-fails (posted by Manuel ALberto Snchez Hernndez)

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mind prefixing, you can "prefix" with an underscore. Sure it'll actually be part of the variable's name, but it'll *look* like a prefixed reserved word. Other than that, it is not possible.

Comment: You typically don't want to prefix, because a prefixed underscore typically refers to "non-public" attributes. Postfixing is probably better.

Answer (score 1):

I received an error when using the following:

```
for r in db.call ('ReadCashflows',
                  number = number,
                  from = date_from,
                  to = date_to):
```

I tried using capitals instead and now it works:

```
for r in db.call ('ReadCashflows',
                  number = number,
                  FROM = date_from,
                  TO = date_to):
```

This was possible for me because my database is ORACLE (which is case-insensitive).  Remark on the code above: in my software application the actual parameters in the database are pFROM and pTO; the "p" gets added in the post-processing before the call to the database is made.

Answer (score 1):

```
db.call( ..., **{ 'from' : date_from }, **{ 'to' : date_to })
```

Python doesn't do those check when unpacking.