# etree SubElement attribute name class fails

Tags: python, xml.etree

I need to force python(2.7.5) to use the word class in building a xml file

```
    properties = ET.SubElement(head, "properties", class="model.View$PropertyList")
                                                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

I tried '' or ""

```
    properties = ET.SubElement(head, "properties", "class"="hudson.model.View$PropertyList")
SyntaxError: keyword can't be an expression
```

If I change it to another name (foo), it builds the xml:

```
<properties foo="hudson.model.View$PropertyList" />
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `attrib={}` syntax:

```
head = ET.Element('head')

properties = ET.SubElement(head, "properties", attrib={'class':"model.View$PropertyList"})

ET.tostring(head)
'<head><properties class="model.View$PropertyList" /></head>'
```

Comment: File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1052, in _raise_serialization_error
    "cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)
TypeError: cannot serialize {'class': 'hudson.model.View$PropertyList'} (type dict)

Comment: @user2363318, do you receive this error just by running above code, or do you have another elements?

Comment: I did the wrong import, don't know where I got that from.
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
should be
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

Comment: @user2363318, alright I see `cElementTree`, glad you've solved it :-)