# r['spanFlexTable'](tab1,i=1,from=2,to=3) turn out to be an error

Tags: r, flextable

I want to use python's packages `rpy2` to get a `FlexTable` and merge cells, the code is:

```
r['spanFlexTable'](tab1,i=1,from=2,to=3)
```

But `from` is a key word in python, can someone help me to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

In this post the solution of postfixing an underscore (from_) may work:
[Is it possible to escape a reserved word in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503920/is-it-possible-to-escape-a-reserved-word-in-python)