# Is it possible to declare a function called 'except' in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Currently I am trying to implement an API in Python that originally was written in another programming language. This API has a function called `except`. I am trying to implement this function in Python but obviously this resulted in an error as `except` is already part of the Python language. It's probably bad practice, but does someone know if it's even possible to declare a function called `except`?

```py
def except():
    print('hi')

>>>

    def except():
        ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to escape a reserved word in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503920/is-it-possible-to-escape-a-reserved-word-in-python)

Comment: You could add a variable called `except` to the globals() dictionary, but you still wouldn't be able to call it directly using that name. So basically no.

Comment: Maybe you could just decorate it with an underscore: `def except_():`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not possible; `except` is a Python keyword and cannot be used as a user-defined name in any way. You can find the complete list of keywords through [the `keyword` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/keyword.html).

Answer (score 3):

No it is a reserved keywords. They can't be used to declare a variable or a function.

Comment: Little-realized bit of Python trivia: a function is a variable!

Answer (score 2):

You can't declare a method named "except" cause "except" is a reserved keyword in python but you can use "Except"

Comment: Still, I would highly recommend not to do this, even if you can.